# Is it guaranteed that standard extraction operator>> does not change argument in case of failure?

Tags: c++, extraction-operator

If calling something like `input_stream >> i;` where `i` is of arithmetic type, throws exception or sets badbit etc., is it guaranteed that `i` has not changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before C++11, the value was left as it was, [[reference]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), `value` is left unmodified and `failbit` is set. (until C++11)

But after C++11, no. It is set to `0` if extraction fails (same reference):

> If extraction fails, zero is written to `value` and `failbit` is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and `failbit` flag is set. (since C++11)

Comment: Note that some pre-C++11 implementations failed to comply with that specification

Comment: @M.M: what proof do you have for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the cppreference documentation for [`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) [`std::num_get::get, std::num_get::do_get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) :

> 1-4) Behaves as a FormattedInputFunction. After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, extracts an integer value by calling std::num_get::get()

And then

> Stage 3: conversion and storage:
>   [...]
>   - If the conversion function fails to convert the entire field, the value ​0​ is stored in v