# C++ cin reading string into int type returns 0

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name and age\n";
    string first_name;
    int age;
    cin >> first_name;
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")!\n";
}
```

If I type in `Carlos` for `age` or any other string I get a `0`. How does this work(why)?

Comment: Which C++ text book are you learning from that doesn't explain this in  detail?

Comment: Not "any other string" surely. If you type in 42, you get 42.

Comment: What do mean by why this works? You are inputting a string but reading it into an int. The best guess would be to ignore your input as it does not match the type and return some default value (0). Note int age does not initialize the age to any default value.

Comment: @NeilButterworth it's the third chapter of Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup. All he says is you get a, 'garbage value' that happened to be in that part of memory when you started executing.

Comment: Robert, I don't believe this.
You get garbage only if you print age *before* you do the cin >> age statement.

Comment: @StephanM.G. I do believe it would be garbage. The `cin` failbit is set, but the value of age is likely just the same as what it was before the `cin`. (garbage)

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: Same problem I was having from same textbook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378911/why-does-cin-expecting-an-int-change-the-corresponding-int-variable-to-zero-in

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes either.

Comment: If the input fails, the value of the variable must be what default initialisation would have made it, so for an integer, zero, for a string, the empty string.

Comment: Lol @ people who have no idea how this works, being condescending to others

Comment: Neil Butterworth: This is not true (in general I guess). I printed age after declaring it by int age.
It prints garbage, not 0 (clang).

Comment: @Stephan What version of what compiler are you using? Also, I'm not sure that the second input statement is required to be evaluated.

Comment: @NeilButterworth sorry. It's Clang 6.1 (32767). With GCC 4.8 it's 0 indeed (but still garbage, cf. comments below.).

Comment: @NeilButterworth default-initialization for an `int` means uninitialized.

Comment: @M.M. Indeed - perhaps you would like to provide a more complete answer - AFAIK `cin >> x` is defined to leave `x` having the value zero if what was input was not an integer, for example "foobar".

Comment: [Link to similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828481/is-it-guaranteed-that-standard-extraction-operator-does-not-change-argument-in)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure why the question got down/close votes as it's clearly stated and not broad (and judging by the comments, many people don't know the answer)...

Anyway, for the code:

```
int age;
cin >> age;
```

if the input stream did not contain any digits, then the stream is put into a fail state and `age` is set to `0`. The characters in the input stream remain there; they can be read by a future read operation once the fail state is cleared.

The behaviour of `operator>>` is [summarized on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)  , the full description in the standard is somewhat complicated.

Note: This changed in C++11; commentors reporting garbage output are either running compilers in pre-C++11 mode, or bugged ones.

Comment: Very useful answer.

Comment: Help! How do you undo the effects of this error? I tried doing `cin.clear()` but that doesn't do anything, `std::cin >> rounds` continues to set `rounds` to 0.

Comment: @chbchb55 if there is non-numeric data on the stream then that is the correct behaviour. Do you mean that you want to clear the non-numeric data out of the stream?  (If so, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/1505939)).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure out how to do that earlier on my own, I just needed to ignore until EOL not EOF

Answer (score 4):

If the input cannot be converted to a `int` (in your case), then the `failbit` will be set for `std::cin`. This can be retrieved by calling `std::cin.fail()` .

```
 std::cin >> age;
 if (std::cin.fail()) { 
     std::cout << "data entered is not of int type"; 
 }
```

You can also use `!std::cin` instead of `std::cin.fail()` .

Comment: I wonder if `0` is garbage or `>>` sets the argument to it on failure.

Comment: @Holyblackcat garbage.

Comment: Gill are you sure about this?

Comment: "*If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.*".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sets `0` on failure

Comment: Thanks @GillBates. Are you referencing from the manual?

Comment: Changed In C++11 to 0. Previously it was garbage. Well, garbage in this case. Unmodified I think was the correct wording.