# C++ How do I prevent the program from endlessly repeating input when a char is received instead of an int?

Tags: c++

In the below code, if anything that is not a number is entered, the program seems to continuously enter that input automatically. It translates the input to "0" since n is an int, but it does not act the same way if "0" is actually entered.

I have looked up and down and there does not seem to be a reliable way to say something like

```
if (n != int){cout << "invalid";}
```

I guess my last resort would be to just allow 0 to be a valid input, but I was hoping there's another way.

```
int n;
cout << " \nPlease enter a number 1 to 99,999: ";
cin >> n;

while (n < 1 || n> 99999)
{
    cout << "\nThat is an invalid entry!"
         << "\nPlease enter a number 1 to 99,999: ";
    cin >> n;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of n?

Comment: `n` is an `int`.

Comment: @Martin If I understand your question correctly, n is an int with no previously-assigned value.

Comment: @Andrew `n` is assigned in `cin >> n`. `n` is the input value.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080037/c-cin-reading-string-into-int-type-returns-0

Answer (score 1):

When you try to extract a value from an `std::istream` like `std::cin` and extraction fails, all data remains in the stream for the next input operation. If the same extraction is then tried again, it will again get garbage and fail. And so on.

To repeat trying to extract an `int` from a stream if extraction fails, you should remove all garbage before you try again:

```
#inlcude <limits>
#include <iostream>

// ...

int n;
while(!(std::cin >> n)) { // extraction failed
    std::cin.clear(); // clear error flags
    // ignore everything left in the stream up to a newline:
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Combining that with limiting the value to a number between 1 and 99999:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number 1 to 99999: ";

    while (!(std::cin >> n) || n < 1 || 99999 < n) {
        std::cerr << "Input Error!\n\n";
        std::cin.clear(); // clear error flags
        // ignore everything left in the stream up to a newline:
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue of the runaway loop when letters are entered. However, now I get that runaway loop issue if data outside of 1-99999 is entered whereas before I didn't. And if a number between 1-99999 is entered, the program hangs.

Comment: If you're still having trouble you are not using above code. I suggest you ask a new question including your complete code, sample input and what happens. Since the code in my answer does exactly what it is supposed to please accept my answer.